# Safe to throw an exception created on another thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, thread-safety

I want to catch an exception in a thread A, then pass the exception object to a thread B, and throw it from thread B. Is that safe?

Thread A

```
try {
    // Code that throws exceptions
} catch (Exception e) {
    sendToOtherThread(e);
}
```

Thread B

```
Exception e = receiveException();
throw e;
```

**EDIT**

For sake of clarity: I understand how threading works, and how I should pass the object reference from one thread to the other. The question is more about is it safe to throw an exception object from one thread that did not create it or is there any problem with the class `Exception` itself or the way .NET handles it.

Comment: Yes but (may be) pretty useless because you can't rethrow so you'll overwrite original stacktrace. If that's not what you want you have to wrap the exception and throw the new one.

Comment: I'm very curious to your implementation of `sendToOtherThread` and `receiveException`.

Comment: Let's just say these two method pass the object reference as is. So e in both threads refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* rethrow an exception received from another thread (for example, in a BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event handler), but it would be more usual to wrap it in another exception, to preserve the stack trace:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        throw new SomeException("... message ...", e.Error);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using .NET 4.0, any exceptions thrown by a `Task` are automatically propagated to the parent thread when the `Task` is joined. This is by design and should be perfectly safe. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

Comment: Thanks your answer is good as well but I can only vote for one

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change this:

in Thread B

```
Exception e = receiveException();
throw new Exception("Write something here, for example: 'Received from other thread'", e); // so you keep the stack trace
```

But I'd watch out for caveats (I'm not entirely sure this is 100% safe).

Comment: Thanks for the rewrapping suggestion. But the question is still unanswered :-/

Comment: This is a good idea to wrap your exception to keep track of original thread that throw exception, however as OP said, it is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe, but most probably it will terminate thread B.

Your solution only depends on how you pass your exception object from Thread A to thread B.
if you are putting it in a shared resource you need to lock and release that specific shared resource. Other than that, there is nothing unsafe about your code.

As long as you are not accessing any shared resources in threads everything else should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

`Exception` is a class and thus a standard reference type, if you want to pass it between threads (which sounds a bit strange) you need to make sure no one else attempts to modify the instance (especially if you create your own *mutable* exception types).

**Solution A** 

You can do a Producer-Consumer pull-model

```
BlockingCollection<Exception> bc = new BlockingCollection<Exception>();

// thread A - Producer
try
{
    ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    bc.Add(ex);
}


//thread B - Consumer
try
{
    // Consume bc
    while (true)
    {
        var ex = bc.Take();
        //thread sleep
    }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    // IOE means that Take()
    // was called on a completed collection and no
    // No more exceptions, restart checking    
}
```

**Solution B** 

But probably a better idea would be not to use pull-model, as in this case it can waste resources, but rather push-model with thread safe observable collections.