# Making a Thread propagate Exception to upper Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, threadpool

Correct me if I am wrong, but I noticed that the thread selected from the pool via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(GoneFishing)`apparently "swallows" any exception that occurs within that thread.

This caused us a lot of trouble as we have designed an ordered thread chain, so if a thread does not finish well all the following chain is scrambled.

What is the most convenient way to deal with this in a proper fashion ?

Comment: If each thread depends on the previous, why don't you just make the program single-threaded?

Comment: @japreiss : You are totally right. The simple answer to your question is : Because I am really Stupid. We spent weeks trying to design a multi-threaded application to offload the whole load on the chain because it is bombed by millions of bytes of data, before we ended up to your conclusion. I am asking the question just to get insight on threading exception (and defuse my intellectual frustration)

Comment: Having exceptions in tp threads swallowed without catch requires a time-machine back to .NET version 1.x

Comment: @HansPassant : Sorry but I did not understand your comment

Comment: You assert that exceptions are getting swallowed.  That only happened in .NET 1.x, not in .NET 2.0 and later.

Comment: Instead of a thread-chain, you should use a work-chain where, ideally, any task can be performed by any thread and the tasks are communicated on queues.  If one task item/object bombs at some stage, load it up with the errror info and queue it to the logger instead of the next queue in the chain, or pool).

Comment: So what's the conclusion so far? Are you indeed using an old .NET version or is the problem not resolved yet?

Comment: @HansPassant I am using .Net 4 and so far, when an exception happens in a separate thread I have no exceptions in the main Thread. Same thing for a BackGroundWorker

Answer (score 3):

If you consider using .NET 4.0, any exceptions thrown by a `Task` are automatically propagated to the parent thread when the `Task` is joined. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

For other related solutions check this question: [Safe to throw an exception created on another thread C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326544/safe-to-throw-an-exception-created-on-another-thread-c-sharp/11327211#11327211)

Comment: +1. And if you don't join the `Task`, you can always `ContinueOnFaulted` and re-throw the exception by yourself in continuation.

Comment: Sorry but... This always puzzled me : What's the point in using a Thread if we just for it to finish using Join ?

Comment: @Mika Jacobi: There are plenty of situations when you will need to wait for a thread to finish. Imagine spawning several threads to do activities in parallel, then waiting for them to finish and then using their results to do something else.

Comment: @Tudor - there are very few times when anyone should wait for a thread to actually terminate.  Signaling a task completion is fine, continually creating threads and waiting with Join() is just asking for problems - poor overall performance and lockups.  If Join() was striken from the language, (and Java, and Delphi TThread.WaitFor), then there would be fewer problems overall - developers would be forced to use sane, efficient inter-thread comms, lifetime-of-app threads and thread pools.

Comment: @Martin James: I'm afraid I don't agree. Depending on the case, signaling a thread to terminate is also followed by a join to make sure the termination actually happens before moving on. And I don't see how join can lead to more problems, since its purpose is very clear. It cannot be used for a different purpose by accident.

Comment: The actual act of signaling a thread to terminate is the problem.  If you take that away, there is nothing for Join() to do.  There is only one certain way of stopping a thread in any state on any core, and that's only available to an OS on process termination.  If developers would stop stopping threads, there would be no stopping-threads problems :)